# How to populate Dropdownlist with server Folder Filenames

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I have added a folder in My project With Name (ReportFile) and I am saving xml Files in that Folder.

i want to Show all `Xml` File Name in a `DropDownList` 
(that are stored in that folder)

My DropDown:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReportTemplate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Yes there is. Google `Directory.GetFiles`

Comment: and How to populate all file names in DropDownList?

Comment: By binding the array of files/folders to a DDL.

Comment: ok i am going to try that thanks VDWWD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Page_Load of the code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reportFolderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports"); //change the "~/Reports" to your report folder name

        IEnumerable<string> xmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(reportFolderPath, "*.xml");

        //As a common practice server file path should not be shown to the client, use file name instead
        xmlFiles = xmlFiles.Select(o => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(o)).Where(o => o.Contains("Arun"));;

        ddlReportTemplate.DataSource = xmlFiles;
        ddlReportTemplate.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: You mean "Arun" in the content of the xml file, or in the file name?

Comment: You could add a call to the Where function to filter the file name, or if you want to filter the full file path, put the Where before the Select. Check the updated answer

Comment: could you try debug the code, set a break point at the line
`xmlFiles = xmlFiles.Select(o => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(o)).Where(o => o.Contains("Arun"));`
and check the different of xmlFiles before and after the line?

Comment: Evan I am trying let you know in some times if it won't work

Comment: That's weird,   please try debug it again and inspect the `ddlReportTemplate.Items` **after** `ddlReportTemplate.DataBind();`
The Items should contain the exact 3 item respecting the right result